# re search cannot find hex bytes with letters [python 3.6]

Tags: regex, python-3.x

```
pattern = b'\x08\x00\x2a\x00'
re.search(b'\x08', pattern).end()
>> 1

re.search(b'\x2a',pattern).end()
>> error: nothing to repeat at position 0
```

I am trying to search for a byte pattern in a dicom file, if it includes a hex value a-f, it gets an error.

Using str.find seems to work, but I was wondering if there is a way to make re serch work as well

Comment: Use a raw string literal, [`rb'\x2a'`](https://ideone.com/uxXkB8).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `'\x2a'` is an escape sequence that represents a `*` char. It is a quantifier that repeats the preceding pattern 0 or more times. You want to match a `*` char, so you may either tell the regex engine to search for an escaped `*`, `b'\\\x2a'`, a regular string literal that represents a `\*` literal string, or use a hex entity with a *regex escape*, `rb'\x2a'`, a raw string literal that repesents a literal `\x2a` string.

```
print(re.search(rb'\x2a',b'\x08\x00\x2a\x00').end())  # => 3
print(re.search(b'\\\x2a',b'\x08\x00\x2a\x00').end()) # => 3
```

See the [Python 3 demo](https://ideone.com/chQZGW).

Comment: thanks, it worked! If anyone else is reading this, and you need to input the pattern as a variable: re.escape(pattern)